# Ionic 3 pre-loading data array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So here is my problem, I collect data via the API of the movie DB in a provider called "TheMoviedbServicesProvider" and which is stored in a **model**.
I manage to collect the data in the HTML part, but when I try to retrieve the informations in the .ts file it worries me that the variable is **undefined**. So what did I do and create a button and place a **console.log** hooked to it and I realized that it worked once the page was loaded completely. I would like to find a way to solve this problem.

**here is the code in the models**

```
import {TheMovieDbApiConfigImage} from './themoviedbapi-config-image-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiChangeKeys} from './themoviedbapi-config-change-key-model';

export class TheMovieDbApiConfig {
    change_keys: TheMovieDbApiChangeKeys[];
    images: TheMovieDbApiConfigImage[];
}
```

and

```
import  {BackdropSizes} from './backdropsizes';
import  {LogoSizes} from './logosizes';
import  {PosteSizes} from './postesizes';
import  {ProfileSizes} from './profilesizes';
import  {StillSizes} from './stillsizes';

export class TheMovieDbApiConfigImage {
    backdrop_sizes: BackdropSizes[];
    base_url: string;
    logo_sizes: LogoSizes[];    
    poster_sizes: PosteSizes[];
    profile_sizes: ProfileSizes[];
    secure_base_url: string;
    still_sizes: StillSizes[];
}
```

**Provider**

```
// Core companents

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// RxJS

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// Models //
import {TheMovieDbApiSearch} from '../models/search/themoviedbapi-search-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiConfig} from '../models/config/themoviedbapi-config-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiDescription} from '../models/description/themoviedbapi-desciption-model';

/*
  Generated class for the ThemoviesdbServicesProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/

@Injectable()
export class TheMoviedbServicesProvider {

  private baseUrl: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
  private apiConf : string = 'configuration?api_key=';
  private apiSearch : string = 'search/movie?api_key=';

  private apiKey: string = '078016f3132847b07af647afd854c75e';

  configMovie : TheMovieDbApiConfig = new TheMovieDbApiConfig();

    constructor(private http: Http) {
      this.resultConfig();
  }

  public getConfig(): Promise<TheMovieDbApiConfig> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.apiConf}${this.apiKey}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiConfig)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }

  public resultConfig() {
    this.getConfig()
        .then(configMovieFetched => {
        this.configMovie = configMovieFetched;
    })
  }

  public getUpcoming() {
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=${this.apiKey}&language=fr-FR&page=1`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)
  }

  public getMovies(arg, arg1, arg2, arg3): Promise<TheMovieDbApiSearch> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.apiSearch}${this.apiKey}&language=${arg}&query=${arg1}&page=${arg2}&include_adult=${arg3}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiSearch)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }

  public getChoice(arg, arg1): Promise<TheMovieDbApiDescription> {

    const url = `${this.baseUrl}movie/${arg}?api_key=${this.apiKey}&language=${arg1}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as TheMovieDbApiDescription)
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue : ') + error)

  }


}
```

**Prez.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Providers //
import {TheMoviedbServicesProvider} from '../../providers/themoviedb-services';

// Models //
import {TheMovieDbApiConfig} from '../../models/config/themoviedbapi-config-model';
import {TheMovieDbApiDescription} from '../../models/description/themoviedbapi-desciption-model';

/**
 * Generated class for the PrezPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage({
    defaultHistory: ['FilmPage']
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-prez',
  templateUrl: 'prez.html',
})
export class PrezPage {

    choiceMovie : TheMovieDbApiDescription = new TheMovieDbApiDescription();
    id: number;
    langue: string;
  urlJaquette: string;
    manuJaquette: string;
    jaquettePerso: string;
  format: string;
  qualite: string;
  lang: string;
  sousTitre: string;
  release: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private themoviedbServicesProvider: TheMoviedbServicesProvider) {
    this.id = this.navParams.get('id');
      this.langue = this.navParams.get('langue');
    console.log(this.id);
    this.resultGetChoice(this.id, this.langue);

    this.testConsole();

    if(this.choiceMovie['poster_path'] == null || '') {
         this.urlJaquette = '../../assets/imgs/no-image.PNG';
      } else {
         this.urlJaquette = this.themoviedbServicesProvider.configMovie['images']['base_url'] + this.themoviedbServicesProvider['images']['backdrop_sizes'][0] + this.choiceMovie['poster_path'];
      }
  }

  resultGetChoice(arg, arg1) {
      this.themoviedbServicesProvider.getChoice(arg, arg1)
        .then(choiceMovieFetched => {
                this.choiceMovie = choiceMovieFetched;
                console.log(this.choiceMovie);
            })
  }

  testConsole() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.themoviedbServicesProvider.configMovie['images']['secure_base_url'] + this.themoviedbServicesProvider.configMovie['images']['backdrop_sizes'][0] + this.choiceMovie['poster_path']);
    }, 60000)
  }

button () {
     console.log(this.themoviedbServicesProvider.configMovie['images']['secure_base_url'] + this.themoviedbServicesProvider.configMovie['images']['backdrop_sizes'][0] + this.choiceMovie['poster_path']);
}

}
```

To make it simple in the provider I created the function **testConsole()** which delays the execution of **console.log** with my **concatenation**, when the time of the **60000 ms** are passed it is displayed correctly. Conversely, if it is **not delayed**, I have an error that the variable is **undefined** in the **concatenation**. So I have to find a way to load the data before the page is fully displayed. Can you help me !!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer, though I don't use Ionic and not sure how to translate this into something you can use from Ionic.

**Service method to retrieve data**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
}
```

Note that it returns an Observable and does not work with promises.

**Component calling this method**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(
            (movies: IMovie[]) => {
                this.movies = movies;
                // Any other code here
            },
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Any code you add to the first function passed to the `subscribe` method will be run *after* the code is retrieved.

The above is the *standard* pattern used in Angular for http (see the docs) and helps ensure that any operations on the data are performed after the data is retrieved.

Comment: Are you using the HttpClientModule? My code above is using the Angular 4.3 and above HttpClientModule instead of the older HttpModule.

Comment: Do you have the `HttpClient` import and constructor I showed above? There are two different things: `HttpClientModule` is a module you need to add to the `imports` array of your `AppModule`. `HttpClient` is what you need to use in the service.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, http is asynchronous. You send a request and at some later point in time you get a response.

One way you can ensure that all of the data for a route is loaded prior to displaying the page for that route, you can use a route resolver.

For example, here is one of my resolvers:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MovieService } from './movie.service';

@Injectable()
export class MovieResolver implements Resolve<IMovie> {

    constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IMovie> {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.movieService.getMovie(+id);
    }
}
```

This code retrieves an Id from the route, then gets the movie with the defined Id. All of this will occur *before* the movie detail page is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Can you tell me where I need to change my code in **prez.ts** or **the provider** ? And if you do not mind giving me an example with my code, because I'm a beginner. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: A resolver would be a new service that you would create. You can read all about route resolvers here: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: Unfortunately **resolve** does not work on ionic 3, would you have another solution?

Comment: AFAIK, `resolve` is the only way to make your async operation look like a synchronous operation. Alternatively, you have to work within the async world. I'll post another answer.